# Which rocket was shown resupplying the ISS in Designated Survivor?

Tags: identify-this-object, space-art

In the TV show [Designated Survivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Designated_Survivor_(TV_series)) season 2 episode 12 ([S2E12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Designated_Survivor_(season_2))) *The Final Frontier* at 07:47 the following US rocket is shown launching a resupply mission to the ISS.

The rocket detonates during launch.

[image: Rocket]

[image: Explosion]

I have gone through the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncrewed_spaceflights_to_the_International_Space_Station) page for uncrewed flights to the ISS and the launch vehicles and their respective rockets mentioned there, but I couldn't find any with that booster arrangement. I assume this is because this footage is not infact from a launch to the ISS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an older Delta, which as you say, is not (and was never) used to supply the ISS.

[image]

Image source: [Wired article on the Delta II](https://www.wired.com/story/the-delta-ii-rocket-that-gave-us-gps-and-the-mars-rovers-retires/)

Delta II flew its last mission in 2018. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_II))

I don't know if this is the footage used in the show, but one of the Delta missions, [GPS-IIR-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_IIR-1), suffered a really spectacular failure of a solid rocket booster not long after launch, resulting in the most amazing shower of flaming solid propellant that I'm aware of, melting cars in the parking lot, etc.

Some joker dubbed music over it, and the resolution is low, but here's a video of that.

Another video with some higher resolution footage (hat tip to [DevSolar](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/2756/devsolar))

Comment: [Potentially better video of the Delta failure.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJP5ncnLwgE)

Comment: @DevSolar thanks, better resolution indeed. It seemed like there was some unique footage in both videos, so I added yours and kept the other one too. Thanks again.